# RestEasy: Validate that path parameter is integer before conversion to Integer object fails

Tags: resteasy

When I have a rest endpoint like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/user/{id}")
public User getUser(@PathParam("id") Integer id)
```

and the request URI is:

```
/user/abc
```

RestEasy tries to convert abc to Integer and fails with an exception:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Unable to extract parameter from
http request: javax.ws.rs.PathParam("id") value is 'abc' for public org.mypkg.restapi.User
org.mypkg.restapi.resources.UserResource.getUser(java.lang.Integer)
```

Exceptions that describe java classes and methods are not suppose to be sent to client because he knows only URI, not how the URI is mapped and handled by java classes and methods.

It seems to me that every Rest API needs this (pre)validation, so I may be overlooking some mechanism in RestEasy. The same problem occurs with any other type that is not String, like for example Date.

So my question would be: What is the best practice to perform validation that the path parameter is a number before the conversion to Integer is attempted? And return an error message suited for client like "Path parameter id should be an integer" in case it is not?

In case RestEasy does not have a mechanism for this, what about other Rest frameworks?

Comment: Use a regex `@Path("{id: \\d+}")`. With this, anything not a number will give a 404

Comment: Thanks, but from the provided error it is hard tell that it is caused by providing a string instead of a number.

Comment: Keep in mind that Java's integer may also be a negative number and has boundaries (-2147483647 to 2147483648). Thus not all strings made of decimal digits (checked by the regex above) may be sucesfully converted to int or Integer.